# getActivity() returns null in onCreateView() method of Fragment

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments, nullpointerexception

Why does `getActivity()` return null in `onCreateView()` method of fragment?

Comment: Code and exception stacktrace from logcat, please. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this

Comment: I have solved my problem by puting my task on onactivitycreated method.

Answer (score 3):

In this case `getActivity()` is returning *null* because getActivity() gets the activity reference once the `onActivityCreated()` method of activity is called and this method is called after onCreateView() of fragment.

Comment: yes  , we could not call getActivity() method to use the reference of Activity inside fragment  until the fragment not attached or created .